# .NET - System.Timers.Timer question

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I want to ask if a `System.Timers.Timer` instance runs on a single thread, a thread pool, or something else?

If it does run on a single thread, what do you think would be best for this example:

- I want to update all character's health every minute
- I want to update all character's energy every 2 seconds
- I want to update all character's specials every 40 seconds

Should I run them each on a separate thread, run them on a separate event, or run all of those in a single thread having to check the time differences?

Comment: BTW, your question is about the _.NET_ `System.Timers.Timer` component. The C# programming language does not have a timer.

Comment: Take a look at question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Timers.Timer elapsed event uses Threadpool. So multiple threads can be invoked if the interval is less( and elapsed event> interval takes long time to complete). Threadpool runs in background and UI  updates cannot be done outside the UI thread in windows application. You can however use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx)

[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx)

[Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

[difference between invoke and begininvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke)

Answer (score 2):

I would run all the actions from a single timing thread and compute the time differences. This way I would be able to run as many actions as I would like without instantiating more timers.

It's also easier to synchronize actions which occur at the same time interval.

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.aspx:

> The server-based Timer is designed for
>   use with worker threads in a
>   multithreaded environment. Server
>   timers can move among threads to
>   handle the raised Elapsed event,
>   resulting in more accuracy than
>   Windows timers in raising the event on
>   time.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I run them each on a separate thread, run them on a separate event, or run all of those in a single thread having to check the time differences.

In my opinion you should use three timers. Three is a number which should not affect the performance in a negative way.

A big disadvantage when calculating time differences are time-changes (daylight saving times, synchronisation with the Internet).
You would have to use `Environment.TickCount`.