# Cannot access a disposed object - wcf client

Tags: c#, wcf-client, objectdisposedexception

I have a WCF client that I'm having problems with.
From time to time I am getting this exception: `Cannot access a disposed object`. This is how I am opening the connection:

```
private static LeverateCrmServiceClient crm = null;

public static CrmServiceClient Get(string crmCertificateName)
        {

            if (crm != null)
            {
                crm.Close();
            }
            try 
            {
                crm = new LeverateCrmServiceClient("CrmServiceEndpoint");
                crm.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                               StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                               StoreName.My,
                               X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                               crmCertificateName);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                log.Error("Cannot access CRM ", e);
                throw;
            }
            return crm;
        }
```

As you can see, I am closing and reopening the connection each time.
What do you think might be the problem?

Stack:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Message security verification failed. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol'.
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfClosedOrNotOpen()
  at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
  at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
  at Externals.CrmService.ICrmService.GetTradingPlatformAccountDetails(Guid ownerUserId, String organizationName, String businessUnitName, Guid tradingPlatformAccountId)
  at MyAppName.Models.ActionsMetadata.Trader.BuildTrader(Guid tradingPlatformAccountId) in C:\Users\X\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAppName\MyAppName\Models\ActionsMetadata\Trader.cs:line 120
  at MyAppName.Models.ActionsMetadata.Trader.Login(String accountNumber, String password) in C:\Users\X\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAppName\MyAppName\Models\ActionsMetadata\Trader.cs:line 48
  at MyAppName.Models.ActionsMetadata.Handlers.LoginHandler.Handle(StepHandlerWrapper wrapper) in C:\Users\X\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAppName\MyAppName\Models\ActionsMetadata\Handlers\LoginHandler.cs:line 23
  at MyAppName.Models.ActionsMetadata.Handlers.HandlerInvoker.Invoke(IAction brokerAction, ActionStep actionStep, Dictionary`2 stepValues, HttpContext httpContext, BaseStepDataModel model) in C:\Users\X\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAppName\MyAppName\Models\ActionsMetadata\Handlers\StepServerInoker.cs:line 42
  at MyAppName.Controllers.LoginController.Login(String step) in C:\Users\X\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyAppName\MyAppName\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 35
  at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
  at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Comment: This appears to have been answerwed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573526/what-could-be-causing-a-cannot-access-a-disposed-object-error-in-wcf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From that stack trace, I assume you have an ASP.NET MVC application with some code that calls that `Get` method to get a `CrmServiceClient` object, and then proceeds to call various methods on that `CrmServiceClient` object. For example, part of the login process does this.

The way your `Get` method works is, each time it is called, it will first close the `CrmServiceClient` object that it returned previously (regardless of whether or not it is still being used) then create and return a new one.

Imagine two users attempt to log in to your application at almost the same time - within milliseconds of each other. The thread handling the first user's login calls `Get` and gets its `CrmServiceClient` object, then a millisecond later the thread handling the second user's login calls `Get`, which causes the first thread's `CrmServiceClient` object to be closed. However, the first thread is still running, and now when it attempts to call a method on it's `CrmServiceClient` object, it gets a `System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object`.

> "As you can see, I am closing and reopening the connection each time."

The code currently in your `Get` method is not a good way to achive this. You should instead make it the caller's responsibility to close (or dispose) the `CrmServiceClient` object, and you should perhaps rename your `Get` method to `Open` or `Create` to suggest this. Callers should use a `using` statement to ensure that the object is closed/disposed, regardless of any exceptions that occur:

```
using (CrmServiceClient client = CrmServiceFactory.Get("my-crm-certificate"))
{
    client.Something();
    client.GetTradingPlatformAccountDetails();
    client.SomethingElse();
} // client is automatically closed at the end of the 'using' block
```

Comment: Per [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN): "the C# "using" statement results in a call to Dispose(). This is the same as Close(), which may throw exceptions when a network error occurs" resulting in hidden exceptions