# How to tick in .NET Core? Timespan? Ticker?

Tags: .net-core, timer, timespan

I am used to the old WCF way of timers/ticking. I want, for example, a certain method to be called every 25th second. How do I do this in .NET Core?

Comment: What do you mean by `tick`?  Do something every `x` seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Be aware that this Timer is not thread safe - see this question for details: [Timer (System.Threading) thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054056/timer-system-threading-thread-safety)
.

```
namespace TimerApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (new System.Threading.Timer(DoSomething, null , 0, 250))
            {
                // do something else
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            }
        }

        public static void DoSomething(object state)
        {
            // called every 250ms
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```