# Thread-safe execution using System.Threading.Timer and Monitor

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Using a `System.Threading.Timer` results in threads being spun from a `ThreadPool`, which means if the interval of execution for the timer expires while a thread is still processing by order of a previous request, then the same callback will be delegated to execute on another thread. This is obviously going to cause problems in most cases unless the callback is re-entrant aware, but I'm wondering *how* to go about it the best (meaning safe) way.

Let's say we have the following:

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim OneAtATimeLocker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

OneAtATimeCallback = new TimerCallback(OnOneAtATimeTimerElapsed);
OneAtATimeTimer = new Timer(OneAtATimeCallback , null, 0, 1000);
```

Should the whole shebang be be locked down, as such:

```
private void OnOneAtATimeTimerElapsed(object state)
{
    if (OneAtATimeLocker.TryEnterWriteLock(0))
    {
        //get real busy for two seconds or more

        OneAtATimeLocker.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Or, should only entry be managed, and kick out 'trespassers', as such:

```
private void OnOneAtATimeTimerElapsed(object state)
{
    if (!RestrictOneAtATime())
    {
        return;
    }

    //get real busy for two seconds or more

    if(!ReleaseOneAtATime())
    {
        //Well, Hell's bells and buckets of blood!
    }       
}

bool OneAtATimeInProgress = false;

private bool RestrictToOneAtATime()
{
    bool result = false;
    if (OneAtATimeLocker.TryEnterWriteLock(0))
    {
        if(!OneAtATimeInProgress)
        {
            OneAtATimeInProgress = true;
            result = true;
        }
        OneAtATimeLocker.ExitWriteLock();
    }
    return result;
}

private bool ReleaseOneAtATime()
{
    bool result = false;
    //there shouldn't be any 'trying' about it...
    if (OneAtATimeLocker.TryEnterWriteLock(0))
    {            
        if(OneAtATimeInProgress)
        {
            OneAtATimeInProgress = false;
            result = true;
        }
        OneAtATimeLocker.ExitWriteLock();
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Does the first have any performance implications because it locks for the extent of the method?*

*Does the second even offer the safety one might think it does - is something escaping me?*

*Are there any other ways to go about this reliably, and preferably?*

Comment: or you could stop the timer on entry to the tick event handler....and re-enable on exit...

Comment: I want the timer to keep ticking for auditing reasons, but thanks for the effort.

Comment: you want to keep the timer ticking so that it can no work? That's a strange requirement!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lots of ways to deal with this.  A simple way is to just not make the timer periodic, make it a one shot by only setting the *dueTime* argument.  Then re-enable the timer in the callback in a finally block.  That guarantees that the callback cannot run concurrently.

This is of course makes the interval variable by the execution time of the callback.  If that's not desirable and the callback only occasionally takes longer than the timer period then a simple lock will get the job done.  Yet another strategy is Monitor.TryEnter and just give up on the callback if it returns false.  None of these are particularly superior, pick what you like best.

Comment: Rather than stop the timer I'd like to do something else; namely write log entries based on occurrences. Just one of the things I'm on the lookout for is such executions overlapping. Using `Monitor` to wrap the concerned code seems the most appropriate suggestion, I think. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I never mentioned stopping the timer.  Using Monitor.TryEnter() lets you log overlaps.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to your 'one-shot timer' suggestion.

Comment: BTW, are there any noticeable performance implications of any suggestions?

Comment: No, acquiring a lock isn't expensive.  A couple of dozen nanoseconds, give or take.

Comment: For one-shot `System.Threading.Timer`s does one still need to lock since each invocation could/will be a different thread?

Comment: To answer my own question looking at the reference source `Fire()` will always lock on something before invoking the callback https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,9c6e2403064ef532. However its probably not a good idea to rely on an implementation detail..

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different riff on the same concept, if you do not have to process every tick. This simply bails on the current timer tick if you are still processing a previous tick.

```
private int reentrancyCount = 0;
...
OnTick()
{
    try
    {
        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref reentrancyCount) > 1)
            return;

        // Do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref reentrancyCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on if you have to process every tick.  If you just want to update some data periodically to reflect the current state of things, then you're probably okay discarding ticks that occur while the previous tick is being processed.  If, on the other hand, you *must* process each tick, then you have a problem because in those cases you usually have to process each tick in a timely manner.

Also, if your tick handler regularly takes longer than the timer interval, then either your timer interval is too short or your tick handler needs to be optimized.  And you run the risk of having a huge backlog of ticks to process, meaning that whatever status you're updating is somewhat delayed.

If you decide to throw out overlapping ticks (i.e. calls that come in while the previous tick is being handled), I would recommend using a one-shot timer that you reset every time after processing.  That is, rather than discarding ticks make it impossible for overlapping ticks to occur.

Is there a particular reason you're using `ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLock` rather than `Monitor.TryEnter`?

Also, if you're going to use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` or `Monitor`, you should protect them with `try...finally`.  That is, using `Monitor`:

```
if (myLock.TryEnter(0))
{
    try
    {
        // process
    }
    finally
    {
        myLock.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, but I mention in other comments that I actually need to audit the fact that this is happening; but at the same time, I don't want to queue up the requests - they can be discarded, just noted. But `0` means I expect the lock immediately, so they won't be queued, maybe `-1` will wait indefinitely, however.