# Does referencing of Threading.Timer from TimerCallback safes it from GC

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection, closures

Imagine that there is a method:

```
public static void Foo()
{
    Timer timer = null;
    timer = new Timer(
        callback: _ =>
        {
            if (satisfied)
            {
                timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
                return;
            }

            timer.Dispose();
        },
        state: null,
        dueTime: Timeout.Infinite,
        period: Timeout.Infinite);

    timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

When method *Foo()* finishes, the only thing that references *timer* is *callback*. And the only thing that references *callback* is *timer*.
Will that circular referencing safe *timer* from garbage collection?

Comment: Pretty sure it won't prevent the GC from collecting them if the callback function ended. The GC will iterate from available object to available object. The timer isn't available outside, neither is callback. Could be wrong. Waiting for a guru for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Certain timer implementations save themselves, some don't, I never remember which do and which don't; check the documentation for that page.

Comment: Probable answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18137151/4049478 . It seems that because the state is null it won't prevent the GC from collecting it.

Comment: Circular references (having no root) will not prevent GC to collect them. Thus, `timer` may be collected "prematurely" - and your callback might not fire.

Answer (score 0):

From [TFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx):

> As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected.

Note that this is specific to `System.Threading.Timer`. Some other `Timer` classes wind up with an implicit reference from the framework, and so don't require you to explicitly keep a reference to prevent collection.

As always, it pays to read the documentation for any API you're using.