# C# Timers and Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, .net, timer, garbage-collection

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), a reference to System.Threading.Timer should be kept otherwise it will get garbage-collected. So if I run this code, it doesn't write any message (which is the expected behavior):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunTimer();
    GC.Collect();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void RunTimer()
{
    new Timer(s => Console.WriteLine("Hello"), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

However, if I modify the code slightly by storing the timer in a temporary local variable, it survives and writes the message:

```
public static void RunTimer()
{
    var timer = new Timer(s => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
    timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

During garbage collection, there is apparently no way how to access the timer from root or static objects. So can you please explain why the timer survives? Where is the reference preserved?

Comment: This certainly *used* to be true.  Looks like Microsoft finally did something about it, thousands of support calls must have been inspiring.  Not sure when this happened, somewhere around 4.5 or 4.6 I suspect.  They are now kept alive along as they are ticking, [TimerQueue.s_queue](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,75523a07eb2de983) takes care of it.

Comment: Thanks, but then should timer be kept alive in both scenario? Why it survives only the second one? I'm running .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me.  Only the Change() method gets the timer added to the timer queue, the constructor forgets to do that.  Pretty hard to imagine this was intentional, consider reporting it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. Although I still fully don't understand it. If I capture the timer in a closure, despite using buggy constructor, it survives. Why?

    `public static void RunTimer()
    {
        Timer timer = null;
        timer = new Timer(s => Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", timer?.GetType()), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
    }`

Comment: I don't think we are supposed to understand it, such is the way bugs behave.  Just ask the gurus, post to connect.microsoft.com and report what you see.

Comment: Curious. What happens if you wait for pending finalizers after the collection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Timers get automatically garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136735/can-timers-get-automatically-garbage-collected)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each `Timer` references a `TimerHolder`, which references a `TimerQueueTimer`.  The implementation keeps an internal reference to the `TimerQueueTimer` via the call to [`UpdateTimer()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,578).

Under normal circumstances your timer is free to be collected, [finalizing the `TimerHolder`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,744) and removing the `TimerQueueTimer` from the internal queue.  But the simple constructor `Timer(TimerCallback)` [calls `TimerSetup()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,872) with the `Timer` itself as the state.  So in this particular case, the `TimerQueueTimer`'s state references back to the `Timer`, preventing it from being collected.

The effect is not related to keeping a temporary local variable.  It *just so happens* to work due to the internals of the `Timer` mechanism.  It is much clearer and safer to keep a reference to your timer as recommended by MSDN.