# Why was not Timer's callback executed?

Tags: c#, timer

There is a timer, its callback must be executed once:

```
var timer = new Threading.Timer(callback: MyCallback, state: NotNullObject, dueTime: Timeout.Infinite, period: Timeout.Infinite);
//note state is some not-null object
//timer is local variable 

//there is some code...
timer.Change(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan); //launch timer in 5 seconds
```

According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137151/5006880), if state argument is not null then garbage collector does not collect the timer. So why MyCallback never be executed here?

And there is another related question: if state argument is not null and timer is needed for once-only operation does it mean GC can not collect this timer later? i.e. is needless memory consumption in this case?

Comment: Is there a reference to your state object anywhere?

Comment: @eitamal I store this object (or rather reference to it) as key in ConcurrentDictionary (dict is global var)

Comment: How is NotNullObject defined?

Comment: @TaW it's string, I create a local variable which references to string property of some class sample. Next I send it to timer (as state arg) and save in a global Concurrent Dictionary as key (so I think dict must store the same object which is in the timer)

Comment: Hm, not sure here. Strings get copied by value, despite being objects. Can you try using a 'real' reference object to test if that is the problem..