# C# Garbage collection of object that has a running timer

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection

I have created an object that needs to update it's status in a set interval so I am using a Timer for this. Many of these objects are displayed in different lists. And when such a list is reloaded(which happens often) the object is no longer referenced, the timer is still running tho.

I know I can prevent this by calling dispose, but a developer using this object can forgot to implement the call to dispose and I think will cause a mayor memory leak, am I right in this and what tools can I employ to make sure the object get garbage collected.

Below is a simplified version of how the classes are used.

The Object

```
public class Test : IDisposable
{
    protected readonly Timer Timer;
    protected int Count = 0;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public Test()
    {
        Timer = new Timer();
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds;

        Timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        Timer.AutoReset = true;
        Timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Count++;
    }

    public void Dispose() // implementing IDisposable
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Free other state (managed objects).
            }
            Timer.Stop();
            Timer.Elapsed -= Timer_Elapsed;
            Timer.Dispose();

            // Free your own state (unmanaged objects). 
            // Set large fields to null.
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    // Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code.
    ~Test()
    {
        // Simply call Dispose(false).
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

The List class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public List<Test> TestsCollection = new List<Test>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestsCollection.Clear();
        TestsCollection.Add(new Test());
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but a developer using this object can forgot to implement the call to dispose"_ should not be a reason. The 'developer' should know how to use the component. Same applies to `Bitmap` and files, for example. What if the 'developer' inherited your `Test` class and overrides the `Dispose` and forgets to call `base.Dispose()`

Comment: @EvK In my test project the Finalizer is never called tho. So the timers keep ticking away happily forever.

Comment: So the test project has a bug.  Consider fixing it.

Comment: @Hans Passant Well all the code for the test project is posted, I assumed the finalizer was enough hence the test project to test it. But it does not seem to be enough.

Comment: @HansPassant I think in this case destructor is indeed not enough. OP has reference to Timer in a field, and Timer has a reference to object because callback function is not static, so neither of them will be garbage collected and timer will indeed tick forever.

Comment: @HansPassant can you confirm that my answer makes sense (in the part about this setup is not collectible by GC)? I was quite sure when I wrote it but now have some doubts...

Comment: I doubt that [Kelly Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) would approve of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Timers get automatically garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136735/can-timers-get-automatically-garbage-collected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it seems there will indeed be a leak if you won't `Dispose` your `Test`, and finalizer won't help (at least all my tests show that this is how it will behave).

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4962172/5311735) - timer internally registers callback in GCHandle table, which prevents situation that callback might be invalid when it's time to fire it. Because your callback (`Timer_Elapsed`) is not static - that means it holds reference to `this` and so your `Test` object cannot be collected, because there is rooted reference (GCHandle) to your callback. Now, your object in turn has reference to timer, because you store it in a field. So after all, there is reference from root to both your `Test` object and your timer, and neither of them can be garbage collected.

To fix the issue - you need to break some of the strong references. You can do that for example like this:

```
public class Test : IDisposable {
    protected readonly Timer Timer;
    protected int Count = 0;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public Test() {
        Timer = new Timer(Timer_Elapsed, new WeakReference<Test>(this), 0, 1000);
    }

    private static void Timer_Elapsed(object state) {
        var wr = (WeakReference<Test>) state;
        Test test;
        if (wr.TryGetTarget(out test)) {
            test.Count++;
            Console.WriteLine(test.Count);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() // implementing IDisposable
    {
        if (!disposed) {
            Timer.Dispose();
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

There we first replace `System.Timers.Timer` with `System.Threading.Timer` and also make callback method static, so that it no longer prevent parent `Test` object from collection. However, we need to access `Test` object somehow in callback - so we pass `WeakReference` as a state there (we cannot pass object itself because it will create the same situation we are trying to avoid). In callback we check if `Test` object is still alive, and if yes - do what is needed with it.

We also remove destructor because it's not necessary here. When `Test` object is garbage collected - `Timer` will also be collected and it's own destructor will be called.