# Do I have to stop System.Timers.Timer?

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection

So I know because of the Question [Can Timers get automatically garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136735/can-timers-get-automatically-garbage-collected) that the `System.Timers.Timer` will not be garbage collected in the first place.

But my actual question is - do i have to stop or dispose the Timer?

```
private void CreateTimer()
{
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    timer.Interval = 30000;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

I mean this Timer will run forever. But now I have no need anymore for my object that created the Timer in the Method. Do I have to stop or dispose the `Timer` that it gets garbage collected?

Comment: there is a difference between stop and dispose. Stopping a timer would be sth somebody would need during the lifecycle of the timer

Comment: You can check it yourself:  Create something like MesseBox.Show on Elapsed, then kill it owner, e.g, by closing subWindow.

Comment: I don't think it will be garbage collected till you call `dispose` on it. It does not matter whether you `stop` the timer. More here: `Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the Component. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Component object's Finalize method.`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Achilles - There's no guarantee that there is a `Finalize` method or if there is if it is written correctly or if it is even called or not. The rule should be to always call `.Dispose()` explicitly.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree, one should always call `.Dispose()` explicitly, but in this case `Timer` inherits from `Component` which provides implementation for `Finalize()', so the documentation stands correct.  Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az5741fh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Achilles - Yes, but there are still circumstances when the finalizer is not called.

Comment: It is a common misconception that calling `Dispose()` on an object will ensure that the object gets garbage collected. In fact `Dispose()` will release any **unmanaged** resources held by the object, and in case of a timer I believe this amounts to releasing a non-managed Windows timer queue object. An object can only be garbage collected when it's no longer reachable by any roots. If the object still has unmanaged resources they should be released by the finalizer. However, this is bad because it happens after the unmanaged resource could be released and will add work to the finalizer thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>I don't think it will be garbage collected till you call `.Dispose()` on it. It does not matter whether you `.Stop()` the timer.</strike>

So it appears that calling `Timer.Stop()` or setting `Timer.Enabled` to false should be enough, because that would call `Timer.Dispose()` for you.
Ref: [Timer.Enabled](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/c458cff06715bb66.html)

From MSDN:

> Always call Dispose before you release your last reference to the Component. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not be freed until the garbage collector calls the Component object's Finalize method.
>   [More here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you'd like it to be automatically disposed off, then put that logic in a separate method using the `Timer.Elapsed` property as explained [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No - "I don't think it will be garbage collected till you call `.Dispose()` on it." - that's not correct. If there are no live references it will be GC'ed regardless of whether or not `.Dispose()` has been called.

Comment: Stopping the timer is good enough, no explicit Dispose() is required.  It is never required, not what IDisposable was meant to do.  Winforms abuses it but that doesn't extend to the BCL classes.

Comment: Looking at the implementation for Timer class, you are correct. `Timer.Stop()` actually sets `Enabled` to false, which calls `timer.Dispose()`, so calling `Timer.Stop()` should be enough. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I agree that not calling `Dispose` is probably _good enough_ for non-critical apps, but I have to disagree with "it's never required". `Dispose` is akin to picking up trash after yourself, as opposed to relying on the city's cleaning crew to do it for you; it's what a good citizen does. Also, the fact that `Enabled` disposes of the timer is moot: there's no guarantee that this will keep happening in a future .NET version, or that there won't be other unmanaged resources added to the class that will need to be freed _in addition to_ the inner timer, which is what `Dispose` would take care of.