# System.Threading.Timer not working for due time of more than 2 seconds in c#

Tags: c#, timer

I am using System.Threading.Timer to make my current thread wait for a specific time. I am not using any intervals because I do not want the function to repeat itself.
The problem with my code is that my timer does not work for due time values that are more than 2 seconds. Is it a memory issue or some error in my code. Can anyone help. Thanks. 
Here is my sample code.

```
   var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(a =>
                {
                   //Stuff to perform after 10 seconds

                }, null, 10000, 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that a reference to `timer` is being held somewhere, to prevent it from being garbage collected. For more information on this, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136735/can-timers-get-automatically-garbage-collected).

```
class DontGarbageCollect
{
    static System.Threading.Timer timer;

    public void ShowTimer() {
        // Store timer in this.timer to prevent garbage collection
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(a =>
            {
               //Stuff to perform after 10 seconds

            }, null, 10000, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that help me sort out the issue. Just a few edits were done in static timer to "static Timer timer" and this.timer to "timer". And the code worked fine.