# IHostedService in C# doesn't trigger method every time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

This is my code in .net core 5 which wants to trigger a function every 2 minutes. I don't know why `LoadData` function doesn't get triggered after 2 minutes and only get triggered the first time?

```cs
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(LoadData, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async void LoadData(object state)
{
   var res = await _repository.GetAsync();
   //....
}
```

Comment: The timer is no longer in scope. You should make it a field and dispose it manually. ... Or just use `BackgroundService` and a `while{ await Task.Delay()...}` loop...

Comment: More specifically, since it is not in scope (for all running code), it may be eligible for garbage collection, which will stop the timer.

Comment: create `_timer` field and remove `var` from `var _timer = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line:

```
var _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(LoadData, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Will create a timer and save the reference only to local variable, allowing the GC to collect the `System.Threading.Timer`. Workaround can be to introduce a field:

```
System.Threading.Timer _timer;

public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(LoadData, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Also switching to `System.Timers.Timer` could also work (but have not tested it).

See also:

- [Can Timers get automatically garbage collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18136735/2501279)
- [Why does a System.Timers.Timer survive GC but not System.Threading.Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4962172/2501279)