# How do I gracefully stop a System.Threading.Timer?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a Windows Service implemented in C# that needs to do some work every so often. I've implemented this using a `System.Threading.Timer` with a callback method that is responsible for scheduling the next callback. I am having trouble gracefully stopping (i.e. disposing) the timer. Here's some simplified code you can run in a console app that illustrates my problem:

```
const int tickInterval = 1000; // one second

timer = new Timer( state => {
                       // simulate some work that takes ten seconds
                       Thread.Sleep( tickInterval * 10 );

                       // when the work is done, schedule the next callback in one second
                       timer.Change( tickInterval, Timeout.Infinite );
                   },
                   null,
                   tickInterval, // first callback in one second
                   Timeout.Infinite );

// simulate the Windows Service happily running for a while before the user tells it to stop
Thread.Sleep( tickInterval * 3 );

// try to gracefully dispose the timer while a callback is in progress
var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent( false );
timer.Dispose( waitHandle );
waitHandle.WaitOne();
```

The problem is that I get an `ObjectDisposedException` from `timer.Change` on the callback thread while `waitHandle.WaitOne` is blocking. What am I doing wrong?

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95.aspx) for the `Dispose` overload I'm using says:

> The timer is not disposed until all currently queued callbacks have completed.

**Edit: It appears that this statement from the documentation may be incorrect. Can someone verify?**

I know that I could work around the problem by adding some signaling between the callback and the disposal code as Henk Holterman suggested below, but I don't want to do this unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Why can't you let the timer run by itself every 10 seconds? Why are you manually rescheduling it?

Comment: @Tudor: Because sometimes the work takes longer, and I don't want multiple callbacks overlapping in their execution.

Comment: Why are you manually exposing the timer when the service is stopped? When the AppDomain unloads all memory is re-claimed anyway.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: In my real implementation, I'm doing the timer disposal from `ServiceBase.OnStop`. I want to make sure the timer is disposed and no callbacks are in progress before I let the service shut down. I also have other shut down code I need to run, and I don't want to do this until I'm sure the timer is completely gone.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if you are encountering a subtle problem tied to the Thread callback reference as the anonymous delegate to the constructor....what if you (for testing) converted it to a named function...given that the timer fires on a secondary CLR thread..

Comment: @DavidW: In the real Windows Service implementation that I have, the callback *is* a named function and I still run into the same issue.

Comment: @WilliamGross DARN...ok, good enough :)

Comment: That's caused by a [documented race condition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2). You might want to look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35510799/684096) because it shows how to handle this.

Comment: A bit off-topic -- you are creating timer wrong (well at least 12 years ago :-) ). You should always create it idle, and only **after** creation set the timeouts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With this code

```
 timer = new Timer( state => {
                   // simulate some work that takes ten seconds
                   Thread.Sleep( tickInterval * 10 );

                   // when the work is done, schedule the next callback in one second
                   timer.Change( tickInterval, Timeout.Infinite );
               },
               null,
               tickInterval, // first callback in one second
               Timeout.Infinite );
```

it is almost certain that you will Dispose the timer while it is sleeping.

You will have to safeguard the code after Sleep() to detect a Disposed timer.  Since there is no IsDisposed property a quick and dirty `static bool stopping = false;` might do the trick.

Comment: Thank you; I just thought I wouldn't need to do something like that since the documentation states "The timer is not disposed until all currently queued callbacks have completed." What does that sentence mean?

Comment: hat sentence means you should be right but I saw a ObjectDisposed exception on timer.Change(). Get rid of that one anyway, there are other ways to prevent re-entrance.

Comment: Wondering if perhaps the phrase "queued callbacks" literally means additional callbacks that may be pending, but not currently executing, eg a currently executing callback is, by definition, not queued?

Comment: @DavidW: Yeah, maybe. I am just going to work around this problem for now by catching and suppressing `ObjectDisposedException` from `timer.Change` in the callback. Maybe eventually someone from Microsoft will see this and give me a better answer.

Comment: You seem to have a reproducible case that contradicts the docs, consider posting it on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SearchResultsLive.aspx?SearchQuery=threading.timer)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for protecting the callback method from working on a disposed timer:

```
ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
if (!timer.Dispose(waitHandle) || waitHandle.WaitOne((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds)
{
    waitHandle.Close();  // Only close when not timeout
}
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15902261/193178

Answer (score 0):

As described in "Concurrent Programming on Windows":
Create a dummy class InvalidWaitHandle, inheriting from WaitHandle:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class InvalidWaitHandle : WaitHandle
    {

    }
}
```

Hence you can Dispose a System.Threading.Timer properly like this:

```
public static void DisposeTimer()
{
   MyTimer.Dispose(new InvalidWaitHandle());
   MyTimer = null;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the dummy WaitHandle?

Answer (score -4):

You do not need to dispose of the timer to stop it. You can call `Timer.Stop()` or set `Timer.Enabled` to `false`, either of which will stop the timer from running.

Comment: I believe those are members of `System.Timers.Timer`, not `System.Threading.Timer`, which I am using.