# c# System.Threading.Timer wait for dispose

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, dispose

I have a class which uses a Timer. This class implements `IDispose`. I would like to wait in the `Dispose` method until the timer will not fire again.

I implement it like this:

```
private void TimerElapsed(object state)
{
    // do not execute the callback if one callback is still executing
    if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _timerIsExecuting, 1) == 1) 
        return;

    try
    {
        _callback();
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _timerIsExecuting, 0);
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isDisposing, 1) == 1)
        return;

    _timer.Dispose();

    // wait until the callback is not executing anymore, if it was
    while (_timerIsExecuting == 0) 
    { }

    _callback = null;
}
```

Is this implementation correct? I think it mainly depends on the question if _`timerIsExecuting == 0` is an atomic operation. Or would I have to use a `WaitHandle`. For me it seems it would make the code unnecessarily complicated...

I am not an expert in multi-threading, so would be happy about any advice.

Comment: I am developing an ASP.NET application. The timer is disposed on the call of Dispose of the HttpApplication. The reason: A callback could access the logging system. So i have to assure the before disposing the logging system the timer is disposed.

Comment: @LMB Surely if a method has an `IDisposable` you dispose of it.  Yes the `GC` can clean up, but if this is sufficient and efficient why have an `IDisposable`?

Comment: @MAfifi For when you use unmannaged resources.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379541/reliably-stop-system-threading-timer/15902261#15902261

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you have a reason not to use [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)
This has a [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95.aspx) method with a wait handle

And you can do something like,

```
private readonly Timer Timer;
private readonly ManualResetEvent TimerDisposed;
public Constructor()
{
    Timer = ....;
    TimerDisposed = new ManualResetEvent(false);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Timer.Dispose(TimerDisposed);
    TimerDisposed.WaitOne();
    TimerDisposed.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: There's two issues with this code: doesn't support multiple disposal (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx#Anchor_1)) plus there's a [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) race condition where an `ObjectDisposedException` can occur during disposal - this should be mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

Generally one can use the `Timer.Dispose(WaitHandle)` method, but there's a few pitfalls:

### Pitfalls

- Support for multiple-disposal (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx#Anchor_1))

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times. Instance methods other than Dispose can throw an ObjectDisposedException when resources are already disposed.

- ### `Timer.Dispose(WaitHandle)` can return false. It does so in case it's already been disposed (i had to look at the source code). In that case it *won't* set the `WaitHandle` - so don't wait on it! (Note: multiple disposal should be supported)
- not handling a `WaitHandle` timeout. Seriously - what are you waiting for in case you're not interested in a timeout?
- Concurrency issue as mentioned [here on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) where an `ObjectDisposedException` can occur *during* (not after) disposal.
- `Timer.Dispose(WaitHandle)` does not work properly with -`Slim` waithandles, or not as one would expect. For example, the following does *not* work (it blocks forever):

```
 using(var manualResetEventSlim = new ManualResetEventSlim)
 {
     timer.Dispose(manualResetEventSlim.WaitHandle);
     manualResetEventSlim.Wait();
 }
```

### Solution

Well the title is a bit "bold" i guess, but below is my attempt to deal with the issue - a wrapper which handles double-disposal, timeouts, and `ObjectDisposedException`. It does not provide all of the methods on `Timer` though - but feel free to add them.

```
internal class Timer
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _disposalTimeout;

    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;

    private bool _disposeEnded;

    public Timer(TimeSpan disposalTimeout)
    {
        _disposalTimeout = disposalTimeout;
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(HandleTimerElapsed);
    }

    public event Signal Elapsed;

    public void TriggerOnceIn(TimeSpan time)
    {
        try
        {
            _timer.Change(time, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // race condition with Dispose can cause trigger to be called when underlying
            // timer is being disposed - and a change will fail in this case.
            // see 
            // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2
            if (_disposeEnded)
            {
                // we still want to throw the exception in case someone really tries
                // to change the timer after disposal has finished
                // of course there's a slight race condition here where we might not
                // throw even though disposal is already done.
                // since the offending code would most likely already be "failing"
                // unreliably i personally can live with increasing the
                // "unreliable failure" time-window slightly
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleTimerElapsed(object state)
    {
        Elapsed.SafeInvoke();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        using (var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            // returns false on second dispose
            if (_timer.Dispose(waitHandle))
            {
                if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(_disposalTimeout))
                {
                    throw new TimeoutException(
                        "Timeout waiting for timer to stop. (...)");
                }
                _disposeEnded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding `ManualResetEventSlim`, it does work if you change `slim.Wait()` to `slim.WaitHandle.WaitOne()`. I am not sure what's the difference.

Comment: I would avoid throwing `TimeoutException` from your `Dispose`. Users expect that a call to Dispose will not raise an exception.

Comment: @StevenLiekens Then what would you do instead? Wait indefinitely? Notice that when you run a service and it gets shut down, there's normally a timeout involved. If the service does not shut down orderly in due time, it will be forced killed. Now imagine your service hanging in the disposal of this timer... if it gets forced killed, it'll most likely be very hard to diagnose the cause. With an exception, you may have a chance that it is logged and you know what's wrong.

Comment: I think it's okay to continue disposing other resources after the timeout. At least that's how I think the WaitHandle should be used: to give all callbacks a chance to run to completion before disposing other resources used by the callback. If the callback takes too long, dispose the resources anyway after the timeout. The running callback(s) will probably crash with ObjectDisposedException if they try to access the resources after that, but that seems better than hanging the entire application.

Comment: @StevenLiekens I think that timeout expiration should not be silent, and that's why I chose to throw an exception in the dispose. How to deal with the expiration (log, ignore, crash) should be a case by case decision based on usage of the timer component. It is not a decision to be made in a "library component".
Unfortunately .net does not have an established pattern well suited for this. Dispose is just supposed not to throw. I don't see a way to reconcile this with the fact that a timeout is, at least theoretically, possible. Though, if it indicates a bug, I'm fine with it crashing the app.

Comment: Fair, but I think my point is not very clear because you don't have any other resources to Dispose in your example. Let's say you have an open file handle in your Timer component, which can be used by the Timer callbacks. It might be best to forcefully close the file handle after the timeout period. Any callbacks still in-flight will probably throw after that. So I'm not sure the TimeoutException is needed.

Comment: @StevenLiekens
The timer component should work correctly in all scenarios - no matter whether you have different disposable resources or not. If the program fails because another disposable resources already detects an exception, then that's fine. But if there's no disposable resource and the program malfunctions, this malfunction must not go undetected - hence the `TimeoutException`.

Comment: contd: The shutdown example is just an example. You could be getting rid of a temporary component in the system, without actually shutting the system down. If the timer in fact does not get disposed successfully and keeps on operating, this could very well be a significant bug. There's no guarantees that every scenario contains other disposable components which would prevent the timer from successfully operating any further.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "if the timer does not get disposed and keeps on operating". It is my understanding that timer.Dispose(WaitHandle) will always stop the timer and prevent future callbacks, the WaitHandle is only to signal the completion of any unfinished callbacks. They might never finish, but I don't think that warrants a TimeoutException from your timer's Dispose method.

Comment: @StevenLiekens

Even if this is true, the race condition exists where you would consider your component as destroyed (after timeout), but the last callback executes after this => possible significant bug in your software.

Comment: @StevenLiekens
Also note, that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.dispose?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#system-threading-timer-dispose specifically states to use the `Dispose(WaitHandle)` overload to prevent this case from happening (there's a `Remarks` section).

Comment: @StevenLiekens maybe we could agree on the following: it would be good if the caller would make a conscious decision whether a timeout results in an exception or not. Insofar the implementation should be improved.
Note, that while the original `Timer` implementation allows this choice, it doesn't force it to be conscious (it's very likely you would just use `Dispose` or a `using` statement and expecting something else to happen than what does in reality) + it has the problems described in my answer (not actually being compatible with all `WaitHandle`s).

Comment: I don't think it's correct to throw TimeoutException for a long-running callback, which would otherwise still complete successfully. Things only become more interesting when you have other resources to clean up after the timer is stopped, but callbacks are still busy.

Answer (score -1):

> Why you need to dispose the Timer manually? Isn't there any other
> solution. As a rule of thumb, you're better leaving this job to GAC. –
> LMB 56 mins ago
>
> I am developing an ASP.NET application. The timer is disposed on the call of Dispose of the HttpApplication. The reason: A callback
> could access the logging system. So i have to assure the before
> disposing the logging system the timer is disposed. – SACO 50 mins ago

It looks like you have a Producer/Consumer pattern, using the timer as Porducer.

What I'd do in this case, would be to create a ConcurrentQueue() and make the timer enqueue jobs to the queue. And then, use another safe thread to read and execute the jobs.

This would prevent a job from overlapping another, which seems to be a requirement in your code, and also solve the timer disposing problem, since you could `yourQueue == null` before adding jobs.

This is the best design.

Another simple, but not robust, solution, is running the callbacks in a `try` block. I don't recommend to dispose the Timer manually.

Comment: Things like timers are very hard for the GC to handle.  The problem is that if e.g. a timer event serves only to do something to some object "George" every second, the timer will be useful as long as anyone is interested in George, and will cease to be useful once all references to George by potentially-interested entities are abandoned.  One may be able to handle the situation by having a timer hold a `WeakReference` to George, and dispose itself if the weak reference dies; such an approach may use the GC, but is hardly "leaving the job to the GC".