Guarantee System.Timers.Timer is finished
I have a timer I am trying to close down in a dispose method, but I need to be 100% sure that it has finished running and we have no more stray callbacks to the ElapsedEventHandler.
I know that you can't check that the callbacks have finished, so I am trying to cover all the bases to ensure that no crashes occur and that the message all get removed from my queue.
I've implemented a StopTimer bool, so the timer will not restart itself while I am disposing.
I have a SemaphoreSlim blocking timers elapsed method.
I've put in a delay equal to 2X the timers elapsed interval to ensure the timer should have finished it's final cycle.
I'm also unsure if this is the correct approach, or if I should just stop the timer and let GC take care of clean up?
public class MessageWriter : IDisposable
{
    public delegate void WriteMessageDelegate(OutputMessage messageQueue);
    private ConcurrentQueue<OutputMessage> MessageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<OutputMessage>();
    public WriteMessageDelegate OutputToDevice;

    private System.Timers.Timer WriteTimer { get; set; }
    public int TimerInterval { get; set; }
    private SemaphoreSlim WritingMessages;
    private bool RunTimer { get; set; }

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public MessageWriter(double timerInterval)
    {
        TimerInterval = TimerInterval;

        RunTimer = true;

        WritingMessages = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

        WriteTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        WriteTimer.AutoReset = false;
        WriteTimer.Interval = TimerInterval;
        WriteTimer.Elapsed += WriteTimerElapsed;
    }

    private void WriteTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WritingMessages.Wait();

            EmptyQueue();

            if (RunTimer)
                WriteTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Nothing we can do here, this is the logger
            Console.WriteLine("Exception with Log timer - : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            WritingMessages.Release();
        }
    }

    private void EmptyQueue()
    {
        while (MessageQueue.TryDequeue(out var message))
        {
            OutputToDevice?.Invoke(message);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
        }

        //Prevent timer running again
        RunTimer = false;

        //Disable timer if its running
        if (WriteTimer != null)
        {
            WriteTimer.Enabled = false;
            WriteTimer.Stop();
            WriteTimer.Dispose();
        }

        //Wait for double the timer interval
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimerInterval + TimerInterval);

        //Wait until this message writer has finished
        WritingMessages.Wait();

        //Release the semaphore so the timer can run again if it needs to
        WritingMessages.Release();

        //Get rid of any messages left in the queue
        EmptyQueue();

        //Dispose of the delegate
        OutputToDevice = null;

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~MessageWriter()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}


You can't get that guarantee from that wonky Timer class.  Instead use System.Threading.Timer, its Dispose(WaitHandle) overload gives you way to get notified about it really being dead.

I would trade in using the Timer in favor of a while loop with a Task.Delay(time). Then you can pass in a cancellation token and break the loop.

@HansPassant Threading.timer does not have an autoreset, which I rely on as the timer is often set to <500ms.  Is there a good way to get around that?   Would much prefer the threaded timer myself...

@FelixCastor I'll bear that in mind as a fallback if I can't find a good way to do this.

Use the period constructor argument to get a timer that automatically resets.  Or call Change() in the callback.

@HansPassant I can see similar issues with the threading timer - This class gets called a lot, very rapidly, and it loves hunting down race conditions.  Just using that timer threw a disposedexception pretty quickly.  This seems relevant, and raises similar issues : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396440/c-sharp-system-threading-timer-wait-for-dispose

What's the purpose of that timer? If you have that much throughout, I would expect all sorts of problems with this. Not only on dispose.

*throughput not throughout ^^

@Fildor It's a small part of a larger logging system.  The queue is filled by whatever wants to send log messages, and the timer pumps them out to any of the delegates that want to handle messages on the system in question.  Sometimes its a consoleWriter, others a database, it varies.
We don't have any other problems with it though, apart from this shutdown issue it logs millions of messages a day across a lot of different systems.

Then the solution is quite easy: switch to one of the well established and known logging frameworks. But I am guessing you don't want to do that. Then at least lose the timer. You don't need it at all.

And remove that deconstructor.
