# How to dismiss the queued up thread :C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have Timer callback thread which executes a particular function every 1 second. After certain event i am changing the timer to 60 seconds by disposing the old value and setting it to new one (60 seconds). Even after i dispose i see the function is being executed every second. I believe some of the thread request have queued up from the previous timer value since the time take to execute the function roughly takes around 3 seconds. 
This is my thread function

```
 private void ThreadFunction(object sender)
 {          
       getEvent();
       return;
 }
```

This is the getEvent function:

```
private void getEvent() {
mutex.WaitOne()
 //do the task
 .
 .
mutex.ReleaseMutex()
}
```

However even after i change the timer to 60 seconds i still see the above function is being executed every sec

something like this to set to new timer value

```
eventThreadTimer.Dispose();
eventThreadTimer= new System.Threading.Timer(CallBack, null, dueTimeInterval, dueTimeInterval);
```

Could some one help me to over come this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As this answer says

[Reliably stop System.Threading.Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379541/reliably-stop-system-threading-timer)

- Basically you could use `System.Timers.Timer`
- If you cannot do that you can do `this.Timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);`