# How to stop a System.Threading.Timer, then change its parameters and run it again?

Tags: c#, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I created a timer with C#. I can schedule any operation in seconds, minutes or daily.
However, there is a situation where I want to stop this timer, then change its parameters and run it again (ex. when the button is clicked). How can I do it?

Below are the codes I wrote.

SchedulerService.cs

```
public class SchedulerService
{
    private static SchedulerService _instance;
    private List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>();
    private SchedulerService() { }
    public static SchedulerService Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new SchedulerService());
    public void ScheduleTask(int hour, int min, double intervalInHour, Action task)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime firstRun = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, hour, min, 0, 0);
        if (now > firstRun)
        {
            firstRun = firstRun.AddDays(1);
        }
        TimeSpan timeToGo = firstRun - now;
        if (timeToGo <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            timeToGo = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
        var timer = new Timer(x =>
        {
            task.Invoke();
        }, null, timeToGo, TimeSpan.FromHours(intervalInHour));
        timers.Add(timer);
    }
}
```

Scheduler.cs (File inside your root directory)

```
public class Scheduler
{
    public static void IntervalInSeconds(int hour, int sec, double interval, Action task)
    {
        interval = interval / 3600;
        SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, sec, interval, task);
    }
    public static void IntervalInMinutes(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
    {
        interval = interval / 60;
        SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
    }
    public static void IntervalInHours(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
    {
        SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
    }
    public static void IntervalInDays(int hour, int min, double interval, Action task)
    {
        interval = interval * 24;
        SchedulerService.Instance.ScheduleTask(hour, min, interval, task);
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
Scheduler.IntervalInMinutes(hour, minute, interval, () =>
{
    MyFunc();
});
```

Comment: Is this helpful? [Reliably stop System.Threading.Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379541/reliably-stop-system-threading-timer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't re-invent the wheel. Microsoft already has a library that does this nicely for you. You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`.

You can do this kind of thing:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

This will fire an event every second. If you want to stop it just call `subscription.Dispose();`

If you want a different period then pass in something like `TimeSpan.FromDays(2.0)`.

Now, if you want to be able to change the period you can do this:

```
Subject<TimeSpan> subject = new Subject<TimeSpan>();

IObservable<long> interval =
    subject
        .Select(timespan => Observable.Interval(timespan))
        .Switch();

IDisposable subscription =
    interval
        .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Now, to start the interval going I would call this:

```
subject.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
```

If I now want to change it I just do this:

```
subject.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromHours(2.0));
```

And, again, to stop it just call `subscription.Dispose();`.