# .NET 2.0 Timer under Wine (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, ubuntu, wine

I have a VB.NET application, which uses a timer:

```
MyTimer_Tick
    ModifySomeGlobalDateTimeVariables()
    ModifySomeLabels()
```

On Windows it works good, but when I try it on Linux, it crashes after some time. I have Winetricks installed, added all the libraries that I need (I think), dotnet20, corefonts, riched20, riched30, etc.

Any idea why it crashes? (no exceptions, and `...&>log.txt` doesn't work)

Comment: Have you tried running it under mono? `mono myexecutable.exe` without wine

Comment: @EugenRieck no, but I need this to work with Wine

Comment: I changed my `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with `System.Timers.Timer`, now it can't interfere with the UI, and I think it doesn't crash anymore, so if no one has a better idea, I'll make this an answer

Answer (score 2):

According disassemble information, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` during setting the `Enabled` property has `try` block without any `catch` and `re-throw`, so I think your issue is caused by this behaviour.

`System.Timers.Timer` uses `System.Threading.Timer` in background, and has much more clear code during initializing. You can also read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer).

So your choice to change the class is quite right.