# How to run Multiple timer parallel in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two System.Windows.Forms.Timer with different interval having code as below

```
 Private Sub myTimer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myTimer1.Tick
    myTimer1.Enabled = False
    'Code
    myTimer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

 Private Sub myTimer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myTimer2.Tick
    myTimer2.Enabled = False
    'code
    myTimer2.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

but some timer2 not start wroking until timer1 not get finished i want them to run parallel without waiting for each other to finish

Comment: What kind of timer are you using? System.Windows.Forms.Timer or System.Timers.Timer?

Comment: Default one. i didn't add any namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Timer *and* `Thread.Sleep` is not a good idea as `Thread.Sleeps` blocks the execution of any code inside the current thread. Thus, the other timer can't execute.

Use the timer for the "waiting" and leave out the `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: i removed Thread.Sleep but still it is waiting for other timer to complete it code

Comment: Yes - all `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`s run in the same thread. Maybe a `BackgroundWorker`, a `System.Threading.Task` or the `ThreadPool` are better suited for your needs.

Comment: i will glad if you can managed to give example for that on you above answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem I suppose you are using *System.Windows.Forms.Timer* which is designed for a single-threaded environment. I suspect that when you enter in the first event it block execution until you exit from the call (And the Sleep() inside is really a bad choiche).
*System.Timers.Timer* is designed for multithread execution. This means that to call your event, Window use a different Thread without blocking your main thread. Of course this led to the famous problem on the update of user controls from a thread not the UI thread.

This article on [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) explains the difference between the timers available in .NET.

Comment: Ok let me try System.Timers.Time

Comment: @samirprogrammer. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer) discuss the differences between System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer