# Run two timers at the same time

Tags: vb.net

Can I run 2 timers at the same time? timer1 will do a function and timer2 will also do a function. Fire up both timers in a button click. could use some advise and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` then the answer is no you can't run tow timer in the same time ,**Because it is designed for a single-threaded environment**.

But if you use `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer` it will work they designed for multithread execution.

This article on [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) explains the difference between the timers available in .NET.

Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716458/3130395) by Steve.

Comment: Although correct your first paragraph is a bit misleading IMO. It is not merely designed for a single-threaded environment, they actually run on the UI thread and so run synchronously just like everything else on the UI thread