# How to get System.Threading.Timer period

Tags: c#, timer

I use a `System.Threading.Timer` object, and I set its period:

```
// period of 1 second
var timer = new Timer(CallBack, null, 0, 1000);

...
```

Now I want to get the period of my timer, how can I do?

Comment: If you explain why you want to do this perhaps the community can suggest alternative solutions instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no supported way to do that. You have two options:

1) It's best to use [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class, as it's more flexible, and safer to use in case of multi threaded use. If you want to know more about timers, and comparison between `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`, please read [MSDN article about this subject.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

2) Use reflection to access private member holding the period value. There are plenty of [nice articles](http://www.mbaldinger.com/post/Accessing-private-members.aspx) on how to do this, and you can use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to see which field you need to read. (it's timer.m_timer.m_timer.m_period in .NET 4.0, it may be the same in other versions too)

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is not thread safe.

Comment: There is unclarity in the documentation. MSDN Magazine article states `Instances of this timer class can be safely accessed from multiple threads.`. API document says `Any public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`. I lean to trusting the magazine article, because it was written with focus on comparing `Timer` classes. API doc looks like it has generic warning against accessing instance methods from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. That is to say `System.Threading.Timer` does not support getting the period (or any other members as far as I know). The only way to approximately determine the period would be to time it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) there is no way to achieve what you ask for.

Comment: @Nick just that MS did implement this class that way... no other reason IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can't using `System.Threading.Timer` but you can if you use `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, there you have `Timer.Interval` property that you can check. You can further refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer) to see the differences of this two implementations.