# The best overloaded method match for System.Threading.Timer.Timer() has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I'm making a console application that must call a certain method in timed intervals.

I've searched for that and found that the `System.Threading.Timer` class can achieve such a functionality, but I'm not quite following how to implement it.

I tried this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer x = new Timer(test, null, 0, 1000);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error on the `Timer x = new Timer(test, null, 0, 1000);` line that says:

> The best overloaded method match for System.Threading.Timer.Timer(System.Threading.TimerCallback, object, int, int)' has some invalid arguments

I really don't know how to make this work properly, but if anyone has a link or something that can explain timers for a beginner, I'd be grateful.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=VS.100%29.aspx not sure he will understand lambda's but Jon's Answer is spot on.. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library
/system.threading.timercallback.aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that the signature of your `test()` method:

```
public static void test()
```

doesn't match the required signature for `TimerCallback`:

```
public delegate void TimerCallback(
    Object state
)
```

That means you can't create a `TimerCallback` directly from the `test` method. The simplest thing to do is to change the signature of your `test` method:

```
public static void test(Object state)
```

Or you could use a lambda expression in your constructor call:

```
Timer x = new Timer(state => test(), null, 0, 1000);
```

Note that to follow .NET naming conventions, your method name should start with a capital letter, e.g. `Test` rather than `test`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.
But may you provide me with links that talk about delegates, so i can understand what's it all about ?

Answer (score 4):

`TimerCallback` delegate (first argument of the `Timer` constructor you use) takes one argument (state) of type `object`.

All you have to do it to add parameter to the `test` method

```
public static void test(object state)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```

And the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

write the test method as follows to resolve the exception:

```
public static void test(object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
```