# Writing a timer with System.Threading vs System.Timers

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

Can I use this code snippet as a complete replacement to traditional `System.Timers` that will run for as long as my application/service is running?

```
System.Threading timer:

var timeToWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
var t = new Timer(s => OnTimedEvent(), null, timeToWait, interval);

System.Timers timer:

timer = new Timer(interval);
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
timer.Start();
```

The `System.Threading` version works for me so far so good, but are there any long term implications with the above code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Timers.Timer vs System.Threading.Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer)