# What's the most precise timer in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, timer, timing, time-precision

I want to use a timer that allows me to run a specific code at certain intervals but Winforms timer is very inaccurate. I set it to 2 seconds but it goes off as much as 48 seconds. The kind of code I am running is highly dependent on acting as soon as possible so 48 seconds is way too late to do anything.

Also I don't want the timer to eat a lot of CPU cycles because the code I am running is very simple.

Comment: Uh, if it goes off *46 seconds too late*, something is suspect .. such as incorrectly blocking the UI thread. WinForms timers are dispatched on the applicable UI thread where it was created (there is normally one per "native" Window). If you want it to fire *around* a blocking thread then you'll need to introduce a different thread or use a timer that uses a different thread (that isn't being blocked).

Comment: Thanks, I am basically using a BackgroundWorker that calls the Monitor method. The timer is calling RunWorkerAsync. Is this bad?

Comment: BGW.RunWorkerAsync *shouldn't* block. Is there any blocking code in the timer callback such as waiting on the BGW to complete?

Comment: I don't think so, I only parse the links using the HtmlAgilityPack, but they are only 3 pages.

Comment: I have worked a lot with the timers the maximum tolerance of the timers are less than 50 milliseconds per cycle. 46 Seconds is not acceptable at all!

Comment: lol yeah I can see the creation date of the links when they open so had to time it myself and when I did I saw those print outs, basically anything that were larger than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [System.Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Since it's designed for multi-threaded environments it's more accurate than the timer control.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer) as well and also the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) comparison is really deep and complete.

By the way the most accurate timer is `Stopwatch` which is used for calculating the `Code Execution` times and other similar stuffs and it is used by Visual Studio for calculating the performance of the codes so it is clear how precise it should be. But In your case you can not make use of it. I mentioned `StopWatch` for your information and the other who might see this post in future.

Comment: Thanks yeah Stopwatch doesn't have a Tick event :(