# Different behaviour of System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Let me start from saying that it's more a question than a problem that needs to be solved. I have the solution now and things work fine for me. But I wonder why problem occured first time.

This is the code I have right now and it works like I expect:

```
    private void OnNewGameStarted(Game game)
    {
        _activeGames.Add(game);

        TimeSpan delay = game.GetTimeLeft();
        var timer = new Timer(delay.TotalMilliseconds) {AutoReset = false};
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => GameEndedCallback(game);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void GameEndedCallback(Game game)
    {
        if (_statisticsManager.RegisterGame(game))
            _gamesRepository.Save(game);

        _gameStatusSubscriber.GameStatusChanged(game);
    }
```

I used to use System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer and sometimes timer event (GameEndedCallback method) fired and sometimes not. I couldn't find any reason why it was that way.

This is the code I used to initilize timer (other parts are the same):

```
            TimeSpan delay = game.GetTimeLeft();
            new Timer(GameEndedCallback,game,(int)delay.TotalMilliseconds,Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        private void GameEndedCallback(object state)
        {
            var game = (Game) state;
```

Method OnNewGameStarted is event handler and it is called after chain of methods from Fleck webserver when some certain message comes to it.

Comment: Maybe a shot in the dark, but, could it be that your thread pool is depleated of worker threads?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Timers.Timer vs System.Threading.Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) about the 3 timer types and what they do.
the main things are:

- System.Timers.Timer is for multithreading work
- System.Windows.Forms.Timer - from the application UI thread
- System.Threading.Timer - not always thread safe!

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will need to learn more about multithreading to figure out exact reasons of failure with System.Threading.Timer

Comment: Post is a dead link now.  Thanks to Microsoft's cryptic "go-link" format, no clue how to find the original article :(

Answer (score 0):

Timeout.Infinite is The time interval between invocations of callback, in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic signaling. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx
Timeout.Infinite is a constant used to specify an infinite waiting period.
Try this to get perodic calls to the callback

```
new System.Threading.Timer(GameEndedCallback, game, (int)delay.TotalMilliseconds, (int)delay.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: OP is creating a new timer instance for each Game. MoreOver, a Game can end only once :). Periodic signaling is not intended here.

Comment: "I used to use System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer and sometimes timer event (GameEndedCallback method) fired and sometimes not. I couldn't find any reason why it was that way." Callback is not called as per question

Comment: @user2323308 sometimes it was called, so I guess the problem is not in defining proper intervals and delay

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov No, If you see the MSDN. The last parameter is "Period" and if it has the "Timeout.Infinite" which means the period is infinite. So only first time it is called and then becomes disable

Comment: @user2323308 yeap, that is intended behaviour: game can end only once.

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov That mean callback is not called in the first time?

Comment: @user2323308 that's right. I was wondering why Callback function was not called for some games at all

Comment: I think you need to check the calling code to this method.I am also wondering why callback is not called in some cases.