# What is the best-performing timer for Windows Desktop?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, timer

What is the best-performing, free-threaded timer for Windows Desktop, either managed or native? I am looking for the best precision and lowest "tick" callback latency. I thought `CreateWaitableTimer`/`SetWaitableTimer` might be the best: [How To Use a Waitable Timer with an Asynchronous Procedure Call](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184796), but I am not sure.

Comment: *Managed* timer is either of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer). I have no idea about native (managed timer is a wrapper for sure, perhaps it even uses waitable timer itself). If you need very low latency, then you have to write a driver. Precision is achieved by synchronization and it doesn't matter which timer you use (you can even have own `while` loop).

Comment: "Best performing" is way to ambiguous.  CreateTimerQueueTimer() is generally advisable.  Also used in .NET since v4.5

Comment: _...best precision and lowest "tick" callback latency._: native  [Waitable Timer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of articles describing .NET timers: [MSDN detailed description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx), [short table of differences](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2010/12/comparing-net-timer-classes.html), and [CodeProject testing of timers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167365/All-about-NET-Timers-A-Comparison).
**The main difference between them isn't performance or precision** (it is ~0.01s for all, but Windows isn't a real-time OS, so precision can't be guaranteed), but the characteristics described in the second link I provided and explained in more details in other articles.