# Multithreading & thread.sleep freezes gui

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, freeze

I am making a WinForms app in .net 4.0 (vb.net) and I would like to ask:

I am writing a piece of code that needs to run every specific interval. This task will firstly disable a button in the form and then do the work. At 2 points during this work, it must wait for 1sec and then proceed. When finished, it must re-enable the button.

During this whole procedure, I don't want to freeze the gui.

How should I implepent this? Must I use a background worker?

Feel free to answer me in c# or vb.net, whatever you like!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: What I've done so far (I am using Aforge.NET framework to capture a camera screenshot):

I dragged a backgroung worker in the form. In its DoWork event, I entered the name of the main work:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker_camera_DoWork() Handles BackgroundWorker_camera.DoWork

        do_evaluation()

    End Sub
```

The do_evaluation sub must do some work, then wait for a second (for camera device to be ready), capture camera snapshot, wait for another second and finish work:

```
Public Delegate Sub do_evaluationDelegate()
    Public Sub do_evaluation()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New do_evaluationDelegate(AddressOf do_evaluation))
        Return
    End If


    ButtonX_Evaluate.Enabled = False
    ButtonX_restore.Enabled = False


    ...some work...

    evaluate_from_camera()

    ...some work...

     Main.ButtonX_Evaluate.Enabled = True
     Main.ButtonX_restore.Enabled = True

    ReleaseMemory()

End Sub
```

And the evaluate from camera sub:

```
 Public Delegate Sub evaluate_from_cameraDelegate()
    Public Sub evaluate_from_camera()
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New evaluate_from_cameraDelegate(AddressOf evaluate_from_camera))
            Return
        End If

                    Aforge_cam.start_source()



                   'wait for 1sec
                    Thread.Sleep(1000)


                    AddHandler Aforge_cam.videoSource.NewFrame, AddressOf Aforge_cam.video_NewFrame

                    'wait for 1sec
                    Thread.Sleep(1000)

                    Aforge_cam.CloseVideoSource()


    End Sub
```

As the system requires a little time to connect to the hardware cam, the sub must wait for a second after the `Aforge_cam.start_source()` command, in order for the hardware to initialize fully.

Then, adding the handler for a new frame capture event in evaluate _from_camera will cause a new frame to be captured in a public variable "screenshot". As it requires some tenths of a second to capture a frame from the webcam, the code must wait for a capture of a bitmap in screenshot variable in order to continue. Hence the 2 sleep commands.

I begin the process with a `RunWorkerAsync` command to the background worker.
Nevertheless, the GUI freezes and I cannot understand why, since background workers run on a separate thread, right?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. It's hard to answer as lack of information from you. A background worker would work and so would a new thread, but both are different depending on what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Timer` in order to time your operations, using `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread will freeze the GUI and is not meant for such tasks.

Just [choose the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer) that fits you best.