# How to make time loop for retrieving web data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am successfully retrieving the data from webpage by using

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://example.org")
MsgBox(result)
```

However, I need to make it updating, like every 5 minutes it should retrieve the data again. What is the correct approach should be ? Thanks.

Comment: using a timer object or control is probably your best solution, just search c# timer and then in the timer_elapsed event you could pull the data.

Comment: @Kevin Answers should be posted as answers, not comments.

Comment: It looks more like a suggestion. Answers should be more detailed. I think thats what he thought, and he is correct.

Comment: If it's going to run for a long time, you may want to think about a Windows service.

Comment: Regarding timers, might wanna check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a timer set a handler and do the request in every interval

```
Imports System.Timers
Public Class TimerRequest
    Private Shared aTimer As Timer
    Private Shared o as Object
        Public Shared Sub Main()
             aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(300000) ' 5 minutes
             AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
             aTimer.Enabled = True
        End Sub  
        Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
            o = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
            Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
            Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://example.org")
            For i As Integer = 0 To 2
                //your loop here
            Next
        End Sub  
 End Class
```

Comment: @user198989: It looks like VB.NET.

Comment: no, you just need to declare a class, then use the handler

Comment: Some of that probably should be a sub routine - maybe a load event? As they cannot be done at class level.

Comment: Ahh gotcha http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0260__GUI/SetupaneventhandlerfortheTimerElapsedeventcreatesatimerandstartsthetimer.htm

Comment: @user198989 you got it

Comment: I'm getting "not declared" when I use the string. How to fix it ? http://i.snag.gy/wAzMf.jpg

Comment: yep results it's out of scope, put your loop into the OnTimeEvent handler

Comment: for more info about how closure works read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/05/02/closures-in-vb-part-1.aspx

Comment: Couldnt do it mate. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Hmm, but there is not hing left in my sub main, should I call this or, how to make this run ? thanks

Comment: you can move eveything yo your main sub

Comment: Everything ? I mean.. how can I call this, it should be on sub main right? If I move everything you wrote there to sub main, it doesnt work:(

Comment: post it on a gist I'll take a look tomorrow I'll try to help you

Comment: I should call the OnTimedEvent() in  main sub correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64538/discussion-between-jack-the-ripper-and-user198989).