# Await or timeout on an asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Please see the bellow my code

```
HttpResponseMessage messge = client.GetAsync("ladders/get/"+ID+").Result;
if (messge.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

I need this code execute until "result" variable is not null or max 30 minutes. Every minute will be execute bellow code until (result !=null) within 30 minutes.

```
HttpResponseMessage messge = client.GetAsync("ladders/get/"+ID+").Result;
```

Let see, If don't get "result" value within 30 minutes then after 30 min function will be automatically stop & notify to user that value not found. Meanwhile user can access other page.

Please suggest me how can solve this issue .....

Comment: Consider using a timer here. Have the interval at 1 minute, and cancel the timer if you reach 30 minutes or get a result. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer for your options. I'd recommend System.Threading.Timer for your purpose. Also be aware that Timer tick events can overlap if your tick handler takes too long.

Comment: If we're talking about web dev then consider performing the above logic with something like setTimeout/setInterval, polling the webserver every minute.

Answer (score 4):

I'd first advise you not to block using `.Result`. The API's exposed by `HttpClient` are asynchronous by nature. By using it you may introduce deadlocks in your code which you probably don't want.

Basically, what you want to implement is a "first task wins" operation. For this, as `HttpClient.GetAsync` already returns a `Task`, you can another task to it which uses `Task.Delay` which internally uses a timer. And, you'll `await` whichever task completes first:

```
public async Task GetAsync()
{
    var expirationTimeTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
    var responseTask = client.GetAsync("ladders/get/ " + ID);

    var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(expirationTimeTask, responseTask);
    if (finishedTask == expirationTimeTask)
    {
        // If we get here, the timer passed 30 minutes
    }
    else
    {
        // If we get here, we got a response message first.
        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You could furthermore pass a `CancellationToken` to `GetAsync` which you can cancel when `expirationTimeTask` completed first.

Comment: @Jasd You're right. But the OP doesn't seem to need it. But it could be easily added.