# C# System Threading Timer is garbage collected (it suddenly closes)

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I first create a System.Threading.Timer from a private static, like this:

```
 private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        // EL MAIN AHORA ES ESTE
        // declaracion de timer:
        TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(Tick);
        System.Threading.Timer stateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, 0, 10000);

}
```

And the timer as a static public void:

```
 static public void Tick(Object stateInfo)
    {
......
}
```

The problem is that the timer for a while runs correctly, but after a long period of time the time suddenly finish. How can I make it run indefinitely?

I read that I may have to add a "reference" but I have no idea how that is done.

Thanks you!

Comment: How can I do that? thx

Comment: use `System.Timers.Timer` instead of Threading timer

Comment: It works, thanks you. But I think that System.TimersTimer only works on windows form application or not?

Comment: that's not true. you can use that Timer at any application. also other posts on stackoverflow will help if you take a look. like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1416809/4767498,