# Windows service running not doing anything

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

My service is running but it does not do any of the logic i inserted in OnStart,
Also, I am try to log messages to the eventviewer but it does not even get to that part (which i assume is falling before the OnStart..)
Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong? Thanks,

```
 public partial class DSGService : ServiceBase
    {
        private static string ftpPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpPath"];
        private Timer _timer;
        private bool _isRunning;

        public DSGService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        }

        private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToEventViewer("error!:" + e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        }
```

OnStart logic

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _isRunning = false;
            _timer = new Timer
            {
                AutoReset = true,
                Interval = 5000,

            };
            _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.TimerElapsed);
            _timer.Start();
        }
```

code to do things

```
        private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isRunning)
            {
                WriteToEventViewer("isrunning is true");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                _isRunning = true;
                WriteToEventViewer("started");
                //do things..
                    WriteToEventViewer("generated!");
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                _isRunning = false;
                WriteToEventViewer("done");
            }
        }
        private void GenerateAndPublishData(ServerData server)
        {
            try
            {
//do things...

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                WriteToEventViewer(string.Format("error: {0}", ee);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {

            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
                    }
```

write to eventviewer

````
        private void WriteToEventViewer(string msg)
        {
            using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("DSGService"))
            {
                eventLog.Source = "DSGService";
                eventLog.WriteEntry(msg, EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1);
            }
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start method on timer from windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763321/how-to-start-method-on-timer-from-windows-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the result of an exception inside the `TimerElapsed` method, that prevents the timer from restarting. To aviod this, here's what you do:

1. Set the `AutoReset` property of your timer to `false`.
2. Inside the `TimerElapsed` event handler, in the `finally` clause, start the timer again.

This means that even if an exception occured in your `TimerElapsed` event handler, the timer will start again.

Comment: Since all is done there is setting a bool and invoking `WriteToEventViewer`, my bet is on the `WriteToEventViewer` method, which is called before the try block. So, OP may also want to fortify that method itself.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.EventLog requires elevated permissions (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogpermission?view=netframework-4.8), so it is probably throwing a permissions exception in WriteToEventViewer.