# Run thread 20 minutes after every run

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

Hi i have this c# windows form application and i have this thread under the `InitializeComponent()`

now it runs continuously after application start now i want is to run that every 20 minutes after a run
for example

```
run
Wait 20 m.
run 
wait 20 m.
run
....
```

here's the code

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {

                       //some process

                    }
                });
                thread.IsBackground = true;
                thread.Start();
```

I remove the code inside.

what i'm facing is the application is taking too much of the computer network beacause the thread runs a query every milisec so i need only to run the thread every 20minutes after every runs
Hope i make my explanation clear

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Check  the `Thread.Sleep()` method documentation

Comment: Consider a `Timer`. It certainly wouldn't constitute a "major change" - probably < 10 lines of code changed.

Comment: because there's  i thread per job item in the application so if the'res 100 item  i will not use hundred of timer, each item has different  time thats why, sorry i did not meansion it earlyer

Comment: sorry i just can't explain it correctly, it is also running on production already its also one of the reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Task.Delay` and asynchronous lambda:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
                    //some process
                    Console.WriteLine("1");

                }
            });
```

Or use one of .NET [`Timer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21410286/2501279)'s to execute method on specified intervals.

Comment: ow sorry i cant use timer its a existing application so major changes may ocurr if i change

Comment: @KifferVan then try using the snippet above or `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: yep . i'm waiting after 20 minutes so, i'll make a response after it